# GridView ItemClick navigate to another page and show details about the clicked item Windows store app

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-store-apps

i have a `GridView` with item from a list of person list, how can i show details of the clicked item in the next page?

in the main page i have used this code

```
Private Sub itemGridView_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles itemGridView.ItemClick
    Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage1), e.ClickedItem)
End Sub
```

and i have used this in the next page

```
Private Sub NavigationHelper_LoadState(sender As Object, e As Common.LoadStateEventArgs)
    Dim n As Person = TryCast(e.NavigationParameter, Person)
    txt.Text = n.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: @ChrisShao it doesn't update the `txt.Text`, what i want is to pass the person id to the next page and query for the id in my person collection.

Comment: has you set 'NavigationCacheMode' of BlankPage1 to 'Enabled' or 'Required' ?

Comment: @ChrisShaoNo i haven't set it.

Comment: You can debug it to check if the NavigationHelper_LoadState be execued?

Comment: NaviagationHelper_LoadState is executed, i can't query the clicked item in my person collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my code

```
Private Sub itemGridView_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles itemGridView.ItemClick
    Dim person As Person = DirectCast(e.ClickedItem, Person)
    Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage1), person)
End Sub
```

in the next page

```
Private Sub NavigationHelper_LoadState(sender As Object, e As Common.LoadStateEventArgs)
    Dim person As Person = DirectCast(e.NavigationParameter, Person)
    Me.DefaultViewModel("Details") = person
End Sub
```

And in my xaml file i added this

`DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`